# ADB does not recognize tablet

Tags: android, adb

A few months ago, I bought a cheap Android-Tablet (4.4 or sth. | no name)

It worked fine with adb and the explorer before, but now - for some reason - my PC (win10) will not detect the device, if it is in developer mode, even though the tablet "trusts" the pc.

I tried reinstalling the drivers and restarting the device, but it does not work.

Accessing the storage via the Windows Explorer works fine howevery (if developer mode is disabled).

Did anybody ever have a problem like that? How can I fix it?

Comment: I did have a problem like this with a cheap Android - Tablet but I couldn't fix it .

Comment: do you have the option when you connect the tablet to choose mode? choose PTP not MTP

Comment: When that happens, what usually "fixes" it is changing the USB ports.

Comment: what is usb mode that you use ?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by a comment, Switching from MTP to PTP mode (and switching usb debuggin off and on again) sealed the deal.

I still have no idea why it does not work with MTP any more though.